# Silverlight DataBinding to properties of object

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, viewmodel

I have a silverlight ChildWindow.  When I click on a link it opens this child window and displays some data from my ViewModel.  The problem is this isn't updating when the data in the ViewModel is updated.

Sample from Popup:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=AgentExceptionDetail.Action, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
private AgentExceptionDetail _agentExceptionDetail;
public AgentExceptionDetail AgentExceptionDetail
{
  get { return _agentExceptionDetail; }
  set
  {
    if (value != _agentExceptionDetail)
    {
      RaisePropertyChanged("AgentExceptionDetail");
      _agentExceptionDetail = value;
    }
  }
}
```

This AgentExceptionDetail object is populated via a call to RIA-Services.  This call is successful and the data is brought back okay.  The Binding is actually acting like it's Mode=OneTime rather than OneWay because when I close and re-open the popup the data is displayed but the first time the popup opens AgentExceptionDetail=null, being populated when the call comes back.

Is this to do with me raising a property changed event for "AgentExceptionDetail" when the binding is actually looking for "AgentExceptionDetail.Action"?  If so is there a way round this?

Comment: We need a bit more detail, what are you updating? AgentExceptionDetail or its Action property. What does the Action property look like? ... Conceptionally what you are doing looks right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work as you need in your scenario, if I understand your description right. However, I see a serious problem right here:

```
    if (value != _agentExceptionDetail)
    {
      RaisePropertyChanged("AgentExceptionDetail");
      _agentExceptionDetail = value;
    }
```

You are sending your change notification before you actually change anything! Reverse the order of operations to correct this error.

```
    if (value != _agentExceptionDetail)
    {
      _agentExceptionDetail = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("AgentExceptionDetail");
    }
```

Comment: I hang my head in shame... You're right, I was raising the event before changing anything. Schoolboy error! Thank you. I've been staring at it so long that I missed the obvious.